# Horizontalscroll view UI breakdown

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I am trying to make a horizontal scroll just like the one showed image below, I have a horizontal scroll view here but how is it focusing on a single item in list when I scroll(I am asking about the sort of forward effect of middle one)

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Its a coverflow. You can get from github

Comment: Thanks! saved much time.

Answer (score 0):

Her's the link which may help you https://github.com/blessenm/AndroidAutoScrollListView

Comment: Thanks for reply! its called coverflow, got it.